# Extracting Data Between two Different Characters in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, extract

I have data in the following format in Excel:

> ABC - DEF - XYZ; GHI, JKL, MNO, PQR, STU, VWX, YYY, ZZZ

Is is it possible to extract the data between the second hyphen "-" and the semicolon ";" - in this case **XYZ**?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use free regex add-in (http://www.codedawn.com/excel-add-ins.php), with that you can easily create a formula to select the desired text:

`=RegExReplace(A1,"(.*-){2}(.*);.*","$2")`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use Add-in you can use the following:

`=TRIM(MID(A1,SEARCH("-",A1,SEARCH("-",A1,1)+1)+1,SEARCH(";",A1,1)-SEARCH("-",A1,SEARCH("-",A1,1)+1)-1))`

A1 is where you have your string
Search will find the second  "-" (you can copy paste it in your formula if you are not sure") and first ";"
Trim to remove unwanted spaces

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
=TRIM(MID(A1,(FIND("-",A1,(FIND("-",A1)+1))+1),FIND(";",A1,(FIND("-",A1,(FIND("-",A1)+1))+1))-(FIND("-",A1,(FIND("-",A1)+1))+1)))
```

For example:

[image]